# asking credentials when opening worksheet

Tags: tableau-api

I had published my Dashboard to server and while opening it to server it is asking me to login. even I gave the correct credentials it is asking me to login again.

When I try to connect SQL server with the same credentials it is working.

Answer (score 2):

To view a published a workbook (that uses a live connection) without being prompted for credentials, the credentials for the underlying data source must be [embedded](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/embedding-database-credentials-tableau-server?lang=en-us).

Answer (score 0):

How is your data source configured?  Live or Data Extract?

Did you choose the "Embedded Password" option when publishing to the server?